# Django - opening static file from server

Tags: django, file

I've carefully read [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/) and multiple discussions related to the topic, but still can't figure out where the buck stops. I just want to open a static file in Django view, write some content into it and save it using

```
f = open('/static/egais_files/temp.txt', 'w')
```

method.

My settings:

```
"""
Django settings for supermarket_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

#for gmail or goole apps
from supermarket_project.email_info import EMAIL_USE_TLS,EMAIL_HOST,EMAIL_HOST_USER,EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,EMAIL_PORT
from django.conf.global_settings import ALLOWED_HOSTS

#What Tigran wrote ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT
#What Tigran wrote END ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


import os
#from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_DEBUG

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pvpsr%xjy3ki8ecut2&x=!+&(1q*=u9=(tnz8o371m^%^jntn&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

#ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'person',
    'legal_entity',
    'additional',
    'address',
    'employee',
    'agreement',
    'report',
    'vendor',
    'bootstrap3_datetime',
    'computer_repair',
    'task',
    'egais',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supermarket_project.urls'
#ANONYMOUS_USER_ID=-1
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","templates")],
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supermarket_project.wsgi.application'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

#===============================================================================
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }
#===============================================================================
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'supermarkets_schema',
        'USER': 'edgar',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '10.8.0.1',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        'default-character-set': 'utf8',
    },
    'computer_repair': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'computer_repair',
        'USER': 'edgar',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '10.8.0.1',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        'default-character-set': 'utf8',
    }
}
#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
#        'NAME': 'test',
#        'USER': 'root',
#        'PASSWORD': '1234',
#    }
#}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static")
#STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static-only")]
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
#MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")]
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
     )
```

Looks like everything corresponds to what documentation says. Help me please ! Where's the mistake ???

Answer (score 0):

To open a file you have to pass the path of the file to `open`. You pass the the url.

It should be like this:

```
f = open(os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'egais_files/temp.txt'), 'w')
```

Comment: Thank you. It cannot recognize os.join, despite the fact that I imported os

Comment: Sorry, should be `os.path.join` (like in your settings.py)

Comment: Nope, did not work [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\10.8.0.1\\share/egais_files/temp.txt\\w'

Comment: Try my newest edit :). Do you know the absolute path of STATIC_ROOT or the file? Just use that.

Comment: It doesn't work even with the absolute path. And the strange thing is that is inserts a suprlus slash in the error message .

Comment: \\10.8.0.1\\share\\djprj\\djprj\\static\\static\\egais_files\temp.txt' instead of \\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\static\static\egais_files\temp.txt'

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? I think you have to use `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109176/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-ilse2005).

Answer (score 0):

In the initial code snippet you're attempting to open a file for writing in a subdirectory off the the root of the file system. You will need to ensure two things. The first is that you are writing to the correct location. It is likely that you'll need to change the open statement to something with an absolute path. You will also need to ensure that the `STATIC_ROOT/egais_files` exists before you try to create the file.
For Python 3:

```
import os
import os.path
from django.conf import settings

os.makedirs(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'egais_files'), exist_ok=True)
f = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'egais_files','temp.txt'), 'w')
```

For Python 2:

```
import errno
import os
import os.path
from django.conf import settings

try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'egais_files'))
except OSError as xcpt:
    if rcpt.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        pass
    else:
        raise

f = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'egais_files','temp.txt'), 'w')
```

Comment: Nope, it does not recognize the exist_ok keyword

Comment: I assume that you're using Python 2.x then.  The approach I've got outlined above for guarding when creating the directory is not ideal, but is provided as an example.